# Start GProc as a dependency

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I am trying to start **gproc** as a **dependency** inside the app, but it fails with:

```
{error,{not_started,gproc}}
```

This is my app.src file which is used by Rebar3 when compiling:

```
{application, myapp,
 [{description, "MyApp"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {mod, { my_app, []}},
  {applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib,
    sasl,
    gproc    <--- Dependency, and is compiled with Rebar3
   ]},
  {env,[]},
  {modules, []},

  {maintainers, []},
  {licenses, []},
  {links, []}
 ]}.
```

When starting from the shell with `application:start(gproc).` and then `application:start(myapp).` everything works beautifully. I don't understand why...

Maybe it is because of some sort of race condition?

The shell is started with:

```
erl -pa _build/default/lib/*/ebin -boot start_sasl -eval "application:start(myapp)"
```

**Edit:** When using `rebar3 shell` all works fine, what is the difference from the shell command I am using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
application:ensure_all_started(myapp).
```

The plain `start` tries to start only the requested application, only verifying that the dependencies are already running.

Docs:

- [`application:start/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#start-1):

  > Starts Application. If it is not loaded, the application controller first loads it using load/1. It ensures that any included applications are loaded, but does not start them. That is assumed to be taken care of in the code for Application.
- [`application:ensure_all_started/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1):

  > Equivalent to calling start/1,2 repeatedly on all dependencies that are not yet started for an application

Comment: Thank you! Hard to find this in the docs. If anyone wants to look it up: http://erlang.org/doc/man/application.html